# Ethernet/IP device: able to read attributes using CPPPO, but cannot write

Tags: python, protocols, ethernet, industrial

I am working to build a Python script to communicate with an EtherNet/IP device (Graco PD2K spray system).  The only documentation provided by the vendor is how to configure an Allen Bradley PLC as the client to communicate with the device.

[image: Allen-Bradley Configuration]

Using the following code, I can read the array of attributes at Assembly Instance 100:

```
from cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute import proxy_simple

via = proxy_simple('192.168.10.5')
with via:
     data, = via.read( [('@4/100/3','DINT')] )
```

... which results in receiving back the expected array:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

(39 x 32-bit integers)

When attempting to write to the attributes at Assembly instance 150, I receive `True` back from the controller, but the controller does not update the parameters.  It is expecting 25 x 32-bit integer array:

```
with via:
    result, = via.read([('@4/150/3=(DINT)4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0','@4/150/3')],1)
```

The output from above is:

```
@4/150/3=(DINT)4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 == True
```

If I add one integer to the array (or subtract, or attempt to set other than @4/150/3, I get back `None`, so it is clear I am close on the format and the command is getting through.

I have reached out to the vendor multiple times, and they insist it is a problem with Python (or, more specifically, they do not support Python and recommend integrating with a PLC).

I am wondering if the "Configuration" parameter at Assembly Instance 1 is the issue (see image above).  I have tried multiple versions of the following code to try to write that parameter.  Not fully understanding the EtherNet/IP protocol, I'm not even sure what that particular instance does -- however, that it is a parameter in an Allen-Bradley config indicates it is important in this case.

Code attempted:

```
result, = via.read([('@4/1/3=(USINT)0','@4/1/3')],1)
```

I have tried using the Molex EnIP utility, as well as something similar on SourceForge to take Python out of the equation, but results are similar.  I have also tried the PyComm3 module, but I can't even get it to return Id information.  I have also tried using `-vvv` with the CPPPO command line utils:

`python -m cpppo.server.enip.get_attribute -a 192.168.10.5 '@4/150/3=(DINT)4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0' -vv -S`

Results in (along with much more output that I don't believe is relevant):

```
11-09 12:11:18.119 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   issue      Sending  1 (Context       b'0')
11-09 12:11:18.120 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   pipeline   Issuing     0/  1; curr:   0 - last:  -1 ==   1 depth vs. max   0
11-09 12:11:18.124 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   __next__   Client CIP Rcvd: {
    "send_data.interface": 0,
    "send_data.timeout": 8,
    "send_data.CPF.count": 2,
    "send_data.CPF.item[0].type_id": 0,
    "send_data.CPF.item[0].length": 0,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].type_id": 178,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].length": 4,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].unconnected_send.request.input": "array('B', [144, 0, 0, 0])",
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].unconnected_send.request.service": 144,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].unconnected_send.request.status": 0,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].unconnected_send.request.status_ext.size": 0,
    "send_data.CPF.item[1].unconnected_send.request.set_attribute_single": true
}
11-09 12:11:18.124 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   collect    Receive  1 (Context       b'0')
11-09 12:11:18.124 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   pipeline   Completed   1/  1; curr:   0 - last:   0 ==   0 depth vs. max   0
Mon Nov  9 12:11:18 2020:   0: Single S_A_S      @0x0004/150/3 == True
11-09 12:11:18.124 MainThread enip.cli DETAIL   pipeline   Pipelined   1/  1; curr:   0 - last:   0 ==   0 depth vs. max   0
11-09 12:11:18.125 MainThread enip.get NORMAL   main         1 requests in   0.006s at pipeline depth  0; 153.919 TPS
```

Again, result of the request is `True`, but the controller does not update any of the parameters.

I'm not sure what to try next...